# Openshift - trying to clone repo after creating - asking for strange password

Tags: ssh, passwords, openshift, clone

|||| Trying to clone my openshift application - asking for a password ||||

[a****0@a**** ~]$ git clone ssh://12**********************@diy-a****.rhcloud.com/~/git/diy.git/
Cloning into 'diy'...
12**********************@diy-a****.rhcloud.com's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
12**********************@diy-a****.rhcloud.com's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
12**********************@diy-a****.rhcloud.com's password: 
Permission denied (password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
[a****0@a**** ~]$

|| And This is what that happens, when i try to connect over ssh ==> ||

[a****0@a**** ~]$ ssh 12**********************@diy-a****.rhcloud.com
12**********************@diy-a****.rhcloud.com's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
12**********************@diy-a****.rhcloud.com's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
12**********************@diy-a****.rhcloud.com's password: 
Permission denied (password).

|| What Kind of password is it asking for???
I have already tried my account password, but not working. Is it some  kind of auto-assigned password??||

And I dont even know that if i am the only one with this issue or any other too. Please make a comment if u too have this issue, so that i would get notified that i have a company! 
Thanks in Advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are ABSOLUTELY right. In fact, I was doing everything right! But the problem was there was some sort of censorship in my college internet connection which blocked me doing an ssh connection. It soon WORKED as I used a private internet connection. Anyway thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your git and ssh has access to the needed ssh keys, maybe re-run `rhc setup` to re-create (if needed) and re-upload it to OpenShift Online.

Comment: Yes you are ABSOLUTELY right. In fact, I was doing everything right! But the problem was there was some sort of censorship in my college internet connection which blocked me doing an ssh connection. It soon WORKED as I used a private internet connection. Anyway thanks a lot